# play framework 1.2.5 binding a model (GenericModel) exception (numberformatexception)

Tags: playframework, playframework-1.x

**My Model**:

```
@Entity(name = "WORKFLOW_ROLE")
public class WorkflowRole extends GenericModel {

   @Id
   @Column(name = "IDNR", unique = true, nullable = false, precision = 22, scale = 0)
   @Required
   @Min(0)
   public long id;
}
```

**My Controller-Action**:

```
public static void postNewRole(@Valid models.WorkflowRole role) {
    try
    {
      role.workflow = models.Workflow.findById(role.workflow.id);

      if (validation.hasErrors()) {
        params.flash(); // add http parameters to the flash scope
        validation.keep(); // keep the errors for the next request
        newRole();
      }

      role.create();
      flash.success("Rolle erstellt");
      index();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        params.flash();
        validation.keep();
        flash.put("error", e.getMessage());
        newRole();
    }
}
```

### Now i get follwowing exception if i try to pass the *WorkflowRole.id* as a String in my form:

```
@6chopgia8
Internal Server Error (500) for request POST /workflowrole/postnewrole

Oops: UnexpectedException
An unexpected error occured caused by exception UnexpectedException: Unexpected Error

play.exceptions.UnexpectedException: Unexpected Error
    at play.data.validation.ValidationPlugin.beforeActionInvocation(ValidationPlugin.java:80)
    at play.plugins.PluginCollection.beforeActionInvocation(PluginCollection.java:639)
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:134)
    at Invocation.HTTP Request(Play!)
Caused by: play.exceptions.UnexpectedException: Unexpected Error
    at play.db.jpa.JPAPlugin.bind(JPAPlugin.java:84)
    at play.plugins.PluginCollection.bind(PluginCollection.java:579)
    at play.data.binding.Binder.bind(Binder.java:112)
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.getActionMethodArgs(ActionInvoker.java:651)
    at play.data.validation.ValidationPlugin$Validator.validateAction(ValidationPlugin.java:117)
    at play.data.validation.ValidationPlugin.beforeActionInvocation(ValidationPlugin.java:72)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "sdf"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:48)
    at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:410)
    at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:468)
    at play.data.binding.Binder.internalDirectBind(Binder.java:612)
    at play.data.binding.Binder.directBind(Binder.java:529)
    at play.db.jpa.JPAPlugin.bind(JPAPlugin.java:76)
    ... 8 more
```

Is anybody experiencing similar problems with the binding of generic models in play 1.2.5?

Comment: please add the routing line that calls this controller and the URL you are using to test/cause this exception

Comment: well the route is "/workflowrole/postnewrole WorkflowRole.postnewrole" and the url that i call is "/workflowrole/postnewrole". the data gets postet over a form, the name of the input field is "role.id"

Comment: and you're positive that the value of role.id is not "sdf"... strange.  i would attach the play source to your project and put a breakpoint around Binder.java:529

Comment: @TomCarchrae "sdf" gets passed as roleid but the behaviour i would suspect is a validation error, not a NumberFormatException. it would be interesting to know the reason for the internalDirectBind method and the unhandled exception...

Comment: the exception is only thrown if the binder tries to bind to a field marked with an "Id" annotation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit:  Yes, this appears to be a bug.  Patch here: https://gist.github.com/4242156

---

Try making your ID a Long instead of a long - I suspect this is why the binder crashes.  There is special logic for primitive vars - and I think your case demonstrates a bug.  However, I think if you switch to Long the code should work as expected.

In general, you should avoid primitive values for database bound objects unless you can be 100% certain there are no null values in the database.  (but your code should have worked - so there is a bug)

Comment: unfortunately the exception still occurs with Long usage. but yes, seems like a bug

Comment: yeah - you're right, sorry.  if you want to catch the exception and create a validation error then you can edit the binder code and wrap the parse with a try/catch.  there is a design question though - is a type error the same as a validation error?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the route is defined with POST and not GET.
You should post the complete code to make it easier to pinpoint the issue.

Comment: the route is defined as post